# How to validate that introducing a foreign key constraint won't cause issues

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, subquery, left-join

I have two tables, table A and table B. Table A has a column named customerId. I'd like to create a foreign key between table B's customerId to table A's customerId. I have a massive database, and I'd like to verify that all of table B's customerIds have a valid link to table A's customerIds before introducing the foreign key.

Is there a SQL query to view any rogue data before introducing the foreign key?

Comment: do a LEFT JOIN between the two tables. If you do a A LEFT JOIN B you will get all A records with a value or NULL on B and viceversa

Comment: Just try to crate that FK. In worst case the ALTER statement will fail - But nothing bad will happen to your DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull out offending records like this:

```
select tb.*
from tableb tb
left join tablea ta on ta.customerId = tb.customerId
where ta.customerId is null
```

This gives you all records in `tableb` whose `customerId` do not exist in `tablea`.

Or with `not exists`:

```
select tb.*
from tableb tb
where not exists (select 1 from tablea ta where ta.customerId = tb.customerId)
```

Sometimes it is handy to just list the missing `customerIds`:

```
select tb.customerId, count(*) impacted_records
from tableb tb
where not exists (select 1 from tablea ta where ta.customerId = tb.customerId)
group by tb.customerId
```